# How to increase squid Performance

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I have installed squid3.1.19 and divert all traffic from our network to proxy server from mikrotik router. mikrotik router is the final gateway for our network. After I configure squid, internet connection for our network becomes very very slow. How do I solve this problem.

I have updated squid to 3.3.4 version and followed [this link](http://www.packtpub.com/article/squid-proxy-server-fine-tuning-achieve-better-performance) to tune up squid but no use.

Right now I have commented out all that I have done by above given link, there is no cache as well, squid acting as anonymous proxy not cache proxy but no luck no improvement in speed.

**System Details**

```
OS: Ubuntu server 12.04.
RAM: 1 GB + 256 MB.
HardDisk: 80 GB.
Processor: Pentium 4, 2.40Gz.
Squid: version 3.3.4.
```

**EDIT:**

1. Loading web page is pretty slow.
2. When I set cache in squid, initially it used 17M. I have checked by `du -sh /var/spool/squid3`. I checked next day it was still used 17M after one day internet usage. so basically cache wasn't working properly then I had to comment all cache related lines in `squid.conf` since I decided to have only anonymous proxy.
3. We are 8 people in our network. so 8 people's traffic pass over proxy.
4. We have internet speed at 2Mbps. We had good internet connection with this 2Mbps when there was no proxy server.
5. Speedtest.net result is in error. always ask me for `TryAgain`

Comment: Do you actually have 1256 MB of RAM ? Also is it an IDE HDD or SATA HDD ?

Comment: sorry, it's 1 GB + 256 MB RAM. when I check free RAM as `free -m` I see 800-850 MB is always free and it is IDE HDD.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. I just wasn't sure because it's a somewhat odd amount to have. Is the IDE drive a fairly recent one ? or old one ? Is it running in UDMA-133 mode ?

Comment: HDD is old one, i guess it atleast 10 years old. I don't know how to check whether is it running in UDMA-133 mode

Answer (score -1):

How many users? What do you consider slow? What's the load on the box?
What is slow? Are downloads slow as well or just "getting to the page?" What is the throughput? have you tried running speedtests?

Is Squid really an issue here? What is the download speed form the Squid box? (try something with curl/wget)

Check DNS servers, try puttying Google's into `/etc/resolv.conf`:

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

It's almost impossible to help you out as you are not very specific. We don't knwo what you have tried so far and what is slow. Pings? Downloads? Name resolution? You seems to suggest taht Squid is at issue here but it could be your NIC configuration/MTU/DNS etc etc.

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look again. Let me know if don't understand/want further details. I don't know how to get the details like `load on the box, throughput, download speed from the squid box` since am new for networking